# Как создать папку в той же директории, что и jar-файл

Tags: java

`jar` файл лежит в произвольной директории. Например, `C/files/jar`. Нужно в этой же директории создавать папку. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir(), https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath()

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503581/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Найти jar файл для класса (или путь к классу, если он лежит отдельно) можно так:

```
getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

И дальше уже от этого плясать

Answer (score -1):

В терминале с использованием *nix:

- Находясь в C/files - mkdir yourdirectory

В терминале с использованием *win:

- Находясь в C/files - mkdir yourdirectory или md yourdirectory

Comment: но ведь вопрос про java

Comment: Вы хотите средствами java создать папку?

Comment: Арина, да, средствами java. И при том директория не известна

Comment: Создать директорию и проверить, существует ли уже такая, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28947250/create-a-directory-if-it-does-not-exist-and-then-create-the-files-in-that-direct   А насчет пути. Обычно заранее понятно, куда собирается jar в проекте. Где-то в target. Если вы потом его куда-то перекладываете, то тоже наверняка в определенное место.